# Selecting polygon if their centroid falls in another polygon using PostGIS?

Tags: postgis

I'm trying to select polygons which centroids fall in another polygon:

[image]

```
SELECT smaller_polygons.id
FROM big_polygon
LEFT JOIN big_polygon smaller_polygons
ON ST_Within(ST_Centroid(smaller_polygons.wkb_geometry),big_polygon.wkb_geometry)
```

I expect 33,44 to be selected but I get id of the big polygon.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi BERA, it seems `LEFT JOIN` limits the records to the ones provided by the `big_polygon` table. How about `CROSS JOIN`?

Comment: INNER JOIN seems to work with correct FROM table etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
SELECT 
    smaller_polygons.id
FROM smaller_polygons
INNER JOIN big_polygon
ON ST_Within(ST_Centroid(smaller_polygons.wkb_geometry),big_polygon.wkb_geometry)
```

Comment: what if i want to get all the small polygons that falls inside as well overlapping big polygon?

Comment: @Arpan post a new question with the [Ask Question button](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). Include the code you have tried with